# How to stop holding the last frame in video stream as part of an mp4 container encoded with ffmpeg?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mp4, video-encoding, ffprobe

I'm encoding a dummy mp3 file (7 seconds of white noise) and a dummy mp4 file (silent with a red background image for 4 seconds) together to form a mp4 file. The command to generate this file is:

```
ffmpeg -i dummy.mp3 -itsoffset 0 -t 2 -ss 0 -i dummy.mp4 -c:v copy -map 1:v -map 0:a -copyts output.mp4
```

So as you can see, I truncate dummy.mp4 to 2 seconds (originally 4 seconds). However, when I play `output.mp4` in QuickTime Player, I see the red background image for the whole 7 seconds.

What I want is the dummy.mp4's red background image for 2 seconds, then black (nothing).

How can I achieve this?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually up to the player - whether to redraw with a blank canvas after the last frame has been displayed for its duration.

You can do this in a roundabout way by creating a blank.mp4 with the same properties as dummy.mp4, except for the visual, of course.

Create a text file,

```
file dummy.mp4
outpoint 2
file blank.mp4
```

and then,

`ffmpeg -i dummy.mp3 -itsoffset 0 -f concat -i list.txt -c:v copy -map 1:v -map 0:a output.mp4`

P.S. copyts applies only for inputs

Comment: Thanks @Gyan! I don't know what I would do without you ;P.